# Play midi files using chrome

Tags: embed, midi, midi-instrument

I am using embed player for playing midi files. 
It is playing in mozilla and in explorer how can i play that midi files in chrome, is there any extension or plugin by which i can play midi in chrome.

here is my code

```
<object
id="MediaPlayer" width="300" height="300"
classid="CLSID:6BF52A52-394A-11D3-B153-00C04F79FAA6"
standby="Loading Microsoft Windows Media Player components..."
type="application/x-oleobject">
<param name="Url" value="suite1.mid">
<param name="AutoSize" value="true">
<param name="AutoStart" value="true">
<param name="Balance" value="0">
<param name="DisplaySize" value="0">
<param name="Mute" value="false">
<param name="PlayCount" value="0">
<param name="Rate" value="1.0">
<param name="ShowAudioControls" value="true">
<param name="ShowControls" value="true">
<param name="ShowDisplay" value="true">
<param name="ShowStatusBar" value="true">
<param name="ShowTracker" value="true">
<param name="StretchToFit" value="false">
<param name="TransparentAtStart" value="false">
<param name="Volume" value="100">
<embed type="application/x-mplayer2"
    name="mediaplayer"
    pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer"
    src="suite1.mid"
    Height="300"
    Width="300"
    AutoSize="1"
    AutoStart="1"
    Balance="0"
    DisplaySize="0"
    Mute="0"
    PlayCount="0"
    Rate="1.0"
    ShowAudioControls="1"
    ShowControls="1"
    ShowDisplay="1"
    ShowStatusBar="1"
    ShowTracker="1"
    StretchToFit="0"
    TransparentAtStart="0">
    Volume="100"
</embed>
 </object>
```

It is working on mozilla and explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Media Player will probably not work with Chrome, and will not anyway work for every user. Look at HTML5 (e.g. http://mudcu.be/midi-js/, sources on https://github.com/mudcube/MIDI.js) or Flash (e.g. http://code.google.com/p/flash-midi-player/) MIDI players instead.